# Why is "end if" missing at the end of an if-else sequence?

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

The error is

> teclat.vhdl:57:12: 'if' is expected instead of 'process'

The `end if` is where it is supposed to be. I don't understand why it doesn't compile like it's missing an `end if` always.

```
architecture v1 of teclat is
begin
    process(Buttons, COL, ROW) begin

    if (Buttons(1) = '1') then
        COL <= "100";
        ROW <= "100";
    else if (Buttons(2) = '1') then
        COL <= "010";
        ROW <= "100";
    else if (Buttons(3) = '1') then
        COL <= "001";
        ROW <= "100";
    else 
        ROW <= "111";
    end if;

    end process;
end v1;
```

Answer (score 5):

There is *one* `end if` where it is supposed to be, but you are missing the ones for the remaining `if` statements you opened.

Your code is currently processed as

```
if (Buttons(1) = '1') then
    COL <= "100";
    ROW <= "100";
else
    if (Buttons(2) = '1') then
        COL <= "010";
        ROW <= "100";
    else
        if (Buttons(3) = '1') then
            COL <= "001";
            ROW <= "100";
        else
            ROW <= "111";
        end if;
    end if; -- missing
end if; -- missing
```

Alternatively, use `elsif` to avoid opening so many `if` statements. Now you have only a *single* `if` statement and need only one `end if`.

```
if (Buttons(1) = '1') then
    COL <= "100";
    ROW <= "100";
elsif (Buttons(2) = '1') then
    COL <= "010";
    ROW <= "100";
elsif (Buttons(3) = '1') then
    COL <= "001";
    ROW <= "100";
else
    ROW <= "111";
end if;
```